# Cambiar icono Nav Drawer de lado android

Tags: android, android-drawerlayout

Tengo un activity de tipo nav drawer, el menú siempre sale de la izquierda,logre que saliera de la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito es que las barras (el icono de la izquierda) se mueva a la derecha y poder cambiarlo por otra imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Quieres que el icono se vea en la derecha o también que el menú salga de la derecha?

Comment: @LinaCortés me pregunto a que se debe que tengas que poner el menú a la derecha? lo digo porque si diseñas apps mejor seguir la directrices de Material Design, para si crear ecositema entre todas.

Comment: @Webserveis si lo se, pero trabajo según el diseño que me pasa el diseñador gráfico y el quiere el diseño del menú hacia la derecha.

Comment: hay una manera de cambiar estos valores mediante programación, te dejo una liga de un ejemplo similar. Espero te pueda guiar y ayudar un poco. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22046903/changing-the-android-overflow-menu-icon-programmatically

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Que tal, existen 2 métodos para setear esos 2 valores.. que tanto cómo el ícono izquierda(setNavigationIcon) y para el ícono derecho(setOverflowIcon), bueno prefiero hacerlo mediante código java, que con xml con estilos..

ejemplo:

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_blue);
toolbar.setOverflowIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_navigation_more_vert));
```

como ves `setNavigationIcon()` recibe el id del drawable
y `setNavigationIcon` recibe un drawable

Comment: Me parece que lo que desea el op desea cambiar de posición el icono y el menú no únicamente cambiar el menú.

Comment: Bueno no he intentado eso la verdad, pero parece que el mejor camino es trabajar con las herramientas que tenemos y personalizarlas, o bueno amoldarlas a nuestros requerimientos